# How do I get all dll files within the bin folder to build successfully onto another server via TFS?

Tags: asp.net, tfs, tfsbuild

I have just started using the Build functionality within TFS and I can't see all my dlls being uploaded to the server. I have tried looking online but have failed to find a solution.

So there is a specific dll that has been added to the bin folder in a ASP.NET application and has been referenced and checked in. After I 'Queue New Build' within Team Explorer, it completes successfully.

So when I run the website on the server, it complains that it can't find that dll. And when I access the server and look into IIS Manager, I can see that the dll I have added is not located in the bin folder.

How do I get this to appear there via TFS build?

Comment: Do you have a _PublishedWebsites folder under your build drop?

Comment: @Daniel Mann - Not sure, how do I check this?

Comment: From the completed build, there should be a link at the top that says "Open drop location"

Comment: @Daniel Mann - I clicked "Open drop location" and I can see the _PublishedWebsites folder. I am guessing this is a good thing?

Comment: Yes. The _PublishedWebsites folder should contain your web application, including all of the necessary binaries. Try to deploy from that folder. Let me know if that solves the issue and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @DanielMann - I can see that within the _PublishedWebsites folder that my dll file is not included. Deploying from this location might work if I manually copy my dll into the necessary location. But even so, it will not fix my problem. I want the build process to include my dll automatically without having to add it manually. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55920/discussion-between-daniel-mann-and-give-me-chicken).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by these steps:

1. Adding the dll file to the bin folder locally.
2. When viewing the dll in Solution Explorer, second click it and then select Include in Project (this is what I never did).
3. Second click the References folder and browse to the dll in the bin folder. (not sure if this part was essential, but I did it anyway).
4. Make sure it builds.
5. Check into TFS.
6. View Team Explorer > Builds
7. Second click the build you want to run, and select Queue New Build, then Queue.

After running successfully, I checked the the _PublishedWebsites folder to see if the bin was included. It was. And then I ran the website on the server and WALLA! It worked.